# How to change controller name like product to products

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have products controller like

```
http://domain.com/products
```

where products are listed and for single product details URL is like this

```
http://domain.com/products/view/parameter
```

I want to change my controller name from `products` to `product` for single product details like

```
http://domain.com/product/parameter
```

**NOTE:** Please don't give me direct reference of ellislab manaual because I tried those things.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$route["product/slug"] = "products/view/slug";
```

used this in page route.php

Comment: It works. Cheers...